# SVN in netbeans with google code

Tags: svn, netbeans, google-code

So I've successfully set up SVN on one PC and checked out the code on another. 
Now that I want to commit code from the second machine, I get the following error:

> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E155004: There are unfinished work items in 'FILE'; run 'svn cleanup' first.

If I try to look for the SVN properties, I get the error:

> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E155032: The pristine text with checksum '$sha1$ed182...' was found in the DB but not on disk.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: run 'svn cleanup' first.

Comment: I tried that but got the same "was found in the DB but not on disk" error and now many of the subversion menu items are unusable (grey). Please help...

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an error with your permissions in your local folders copy:

Try to override it with:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 foldername/
```